# IBM HTTP Server - enabling mod_status

Tags: websphere, ihs

I have IHS 8.5.5.3 with WebSphere 8.5.5.3 installed on a Win Server 2012 VM as part of an installation of the IBM Maximo 7.6 system.  I am trying to enable mod_status on IHS to enable me to collect metrics with Datadog from Apache / IHS.  The Maximo system is configured on port 9080, I am trying to setup mod_status on port 80 to be available from http://localhost/server-status or similar.

The existing configuration of IHS appears to deny all by default all routes unless configured otherwise.

I added the following to httpd.conf on the server within the IHS installation:

```
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
<IfModule mod_status.c>
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
order allow, deny
#order deny,allow
#deny from all
#allow from localhost
allow from all
ExtendedStatus On
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

When I browse to http://localhost/server-status from the server I get "Not found - HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."  Is there something I've missed in the config or do I also need to enable a WebGroup / Virtual Host in WebSphere or something elsewhere?

I realise generally speaking it's probably not best-practise to allow anyone to view server-status from anywhere but it's a crash & burn server that I only I have access to.  Thanks.

Comment: Ifmodule mod_status.c where is the .c from? If this is on Windows, is the module really named.so and not .dll (never used  Apache on win, so don't know, but might be worth checking those things)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I would have expected the module to be a dll also on Win not *nix but in C:\IBM\HTTPServer\modules I see two files (among others), mod_status.pdb and mod_status.so.  Based on that and "LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so" already being in the conf file albeit commented out, out of the box, I think that line should be correct.  I *think* "<IfModule mod_status.c>" was in there commented out also but you could be onto something, I'll try changing that later and see if it has any effect.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The text of the error message means the WAS Plugin forwarded this request to WAS. This will happen if you have applications mapped to context root "/", nothing can be served locally by IHS as the WAS Plugin will take control.

You can append the following to httpd.conf to force this URL to be ignored by the WAS Plug-in:

```
SetEnvIf REQUEST_URI ^/server-status$ skipwas=1
```

Notes:

1. `ExtendedStatus On` inside of `<Location>` looks like it would cause
   a startup problem. Presumably something you only injected while
   debugging.  It mut be global (outside of any
   Directory/Location/VirtualHost like section)
2. Please update from 8.5.5.3. You are missing many years worth of recommended maintenance.